# Php excel -> removed records : merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am developing an excel file with use of php-excel library in codignator.

I successfully created excel file from my data.

And i checked it with use of libra-office, And open-office on Ubuntu, it works well.
But as i check it on MS office it gives me this error

> removed records : merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Here is my code if it helps

```
 $fields = array(
        "Rno" => array("Title" => "Sr. No.", "Width" => "5"),
        "field1" => array("Title" => "Scheme", "Width" => "20"),
        "field2" => array("Title" => "Share1", "Width" => "10"),
        "field3" => array("Title" => "Share2", "Width" => "10"),
        "field4" => array("Title" => "Component 1", "Width" => "15"),
        "field5" => array("Title" => "Name of Scheme", "Width" => "30"),
        "total" => array("Title" => "Total " . $year . "-" . $end_year . " (Rs. In Crore) ", "Width" => "20"),
        "field6" => array("Title" => "Component", "Width" => "30"),
        "field7" => array("Title" => "Unit", "Width" => "15"),
        "physical_target" => array("Title" => "target for the year " . $year . "-" . $end_year, "Width" => "15"),
    );

    $this->load->library('excel');
    //activate worksheet number 1
    $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    //name the worksheet
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Export Data');
    // Set Style of header
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:BP1')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:BP1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:BP1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:BP1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:BP2')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:BP2')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:BP2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A2:BP2')->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(46);
    $col = 0;
    // Set the Header Title and width of column
    foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
        $column = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($col);
        if (isset($data[0]->department)) {
            $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, "Name of Department: " . $data[0]->department);
        }
        $this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:J1');
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 2, ucwords($field['Title']));
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($column)->setWidth($field['Width']);
        $col++;
    }
    $row = 3;
    $SerialNo = 1;
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $counter = 1;
        $count = count($data);
        $scheme = "";
        $schemeyear = "";
        $department = "";
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $col = 0;

            $value->componentvaluetype = ($value->componentvaluetype != "Text") ? $value->componentvaluetype : (($value->componettvalueunit != '') ? $value->componettvalueunit : $value->componentvaluetype);
            $value->component = html_entity_decode($value->component);
            $value->schemetitle = html_entity_decode($value->schemetitle);
            foreach ($fields as $field_key => $field_value) {
                $val = @$value->$field_key;
                if ($field_key == "Rno") {
                    $val = $SerialNo;
                } else if (@$field_key == "isapproved") {
                    if ($value->isapproved == -1) {
                        $val = "Pending";
                    } else if ($value->isapproved == 1) {
                        $val = "Approved";
                    } else {
                        $val = "Rejected";
                    }
                }
                $val = str_replace('&amp;', '&', str_replace(array('\r', "\\"), "", str_replace(array('\r\n', '\n'), "\n",  html_entity_decode($val, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))));
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $val);
                $col++;
            }
            if ($scheme == @$value->schemetitle && $schemeyear == @$value->schemebudgetyear) {
                if ($counter == 1) {
                    $first_row = ($row - 1);
                }

                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A' . ($first_row) . ':A' . ($row));
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B' . ($first_row) . ':B' . ($row));
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C' . ($first_row) . ':C' . ($row));
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('D' . ($first_row) . ':D' . ($row));
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('E' . ($first_row) . ':E' . ($row));
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F' . ($first_row) . ':F' . ($row));
                $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('G' . ($first_row) . ':G' . ($row));
                $counter++;
            } else {
                $SerialNo++;
                $counter = 1;
            }
            $scheme = $value->schemetitle;
            $schemeyear = $value->schemebudgetyear;
            $department = $value->department;
            $row++;
        }
    }
    $styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'allborders' => array(
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
            )
        )
    );
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:J' . $row)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:J' . $row)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

    for ($rowa = 1; $rowa <= $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow(); $rowa++) {
        // Set the row height based on its content
        $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($rowa)->setRowHeight(-1);
    }

    ob_end_clean();
    $filename = 'State_OB_' . time() . '.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); //mime type
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"'); //tell browser what's the file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Does the information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34983547/7644018) possibly help? ... The original question has the same error message.

Comment: @PaulT. I also checked this answer but this  answer is for java library and my error is from phpexcel library . And i am not much familiar with this java code.